# Dataframe : Group separate subcolumns with identical column names together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have managed to formulate a dataframe having ~200 columns each having a subcolumn. Now after some calculations, a separate set of values have been stored in the same dataframe with the same column names. Hence they are stored with a different subcolumn name.
My query is how to group these two sets of (column, subcolumn) pairs together.

The following is a smaller subset of a similar representation (What I have):

```
          Date    Column1     Column2   Column3      Column1     Column2   Column3
                      Num         Num       Num       ProdID      ProdID    ProdID
0   2015-01-02        100         106       111           AA          AA        AD
1   2015-01-02        105         118       109           AB          AA        AB
2   2015-01-02        102         173       188           AC          AC        AC
3   2015-01-02        112         101       105           AD          AB        AE
4   2015-01-02        139         191       156           AE          AE        AC
5   2015-01-02        126         172       117           AF          AE        AF
```

The following is what I want :

```
          Date              Column1              Column2                Column3      
                      Num    ProdID       Num     ProdID         Num     ProdID      
0   2015-01-02        100        AA       106         AA         111         AD
1   2015-01-02        105        AB       118         AA         109         AB
2   2015-01-02        102        AC       173         AC         188         AC
3   2015-01-02        112        AD       101         AB         105         AE
4   2015-01-02        139        AE       191         AE         156         AC
5   2015-01-02        126        AF       172         AE         117         AF
```

I have tried the basic groupby statements like

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1)
```

but that doesn't work. I think it's something easy but can't figure it out

Comment: What do you mean "groupby" are you doing computations on the pairs or are you just trying to _sort_ the columns in the dataframe?

Comment: No, I am just trying to bring the subcolumns together under the same column. The computations and value insertions are already done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(columns=[df.columns[0], *sorted(df.columns[1:])])
```

`df.columns[0]` is `Date` which should *not* be sorted. Then the rest of the columns get `sorted` `df.columns[1:]`.

---

Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 3
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(1, (rows * 5) + 1).reshape(-1, 5),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        ['Date', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column1', 'Column2'],
        ['', 'Num', 'Num', 'ProdID', 'ProdID']
    ])
)
df.iloc[:, 0] = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=len(df), freq='D')
```

Before:

```
        Date Column1 Column2 Column1 Column2
                 Num     Num  ProdID  ProdID
0 2021-01-01       2       3       4       5
1 2021-01-02       7       8       9      10
2 2021-01-03      12      13      14      15
```

After `reindex`:

```
        Date Column1        Column2       
                 Num ProdID     Num ProdID
0 2021-01-01       2      4       3      5
1 2021-01-02       7      9       8     10
2 2021-01-03      12     14      13     15
```